# Inconsistent vertical spacing to tooltip on impact block

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, tooltips, people-reached

There's an inconsistency with vectical space for tooltips in impact block of [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current):

Helpful flags tooltip looks generally correct:

> [image: helpful flags]

But others have much more vertical space as expected between data and tooltip itself:

> [image: votes cast]

> [image: people reached]